# How to make an absolute path relative to another?

Tags: python, filepath

Suppose I have two file paths as strings in Python, as an example, let's say they are these two:

```
C:/Users/testUser/Program/main.py
C:/Users/testUser/Program/data/somefile.txt
```

Is there a way, using the `os` module, to generate a relative URL based off of the first one? For example, feeding the two above to produce:

```
data/somefile.txt
```

I realize this is possible with string manipulation, by splitting off the files at the ends and cutting the first string out of the second, but is there a more robust way, probably using the python `os` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to MPlanchard in the comment below, here is the full answer:

```
import os

string1 = "C:/Users/testUser/Program/main.py"
string2 = "C:/Users/testUser/Program/data/somefile.txt"

os.path.relpath(string2, os.path.dirname(string1))
```

Comment: I think what you'll want to do is os.path.relpath(string2, os.path.dirname(string1)) to get the output the asker specified.